# Certificate Validation is SSL Handshake using memcmp or Strcmp?

Tags: ssl

Wanted to know about the pros and cons of using either "memcmp" or "strcmp" for validating the certificates exchanged during SSL Handshake.

My code converts the X509 certificates into PEM format and then do the string comparison to validate the certificates.

Are there any issues which are associated with using strcmp OVER memcmp for validating the certificate received during handshake against a verified certificate already placed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it is hard to know what you do with memcmp or strcmp, but I assume, that you want to check the common name or subject alternative names against the hostname. There were others which used strcmp instead of memcmp for this which resulted in lots of security reports in 2009, see CVE-2009-2408 (firefox), CVE-2009-2702 (KDE), CVE-2009-3767 (OpenLDAP) and some more.